# Android app flickering

Tags: android

I have been writing an app that is targeted for Android 2.1 and works great on almost all devices.
Recently I tried to run it on Android 4.0.3 and it started to flicker (just like gmail app). The weird part is that I changed starting activity to empty one (no controls or layout elements) and it still flickered. Changing target to Google APIs 4.0.3 did not help either.

I am using Google APIs 2.1 currently. Have few external libraries protobuf and RabbitMQ and app permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

no idea what else could have any impact to an empty Activity. 
Has anyone experienced something similar or have any clue what could be happening?

EDIT: I began a new project and went step after step to replicate the problem. It is my class which extends Application and it is flooding the log with:
    `memalloc(26689): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x52172000 size:1949696 offset:0 fd:55`
    `memalloc(26689): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x52172000 size:1949696`

it stops if I comment out line:
`newConfig.locale = locale;`
which is in method:
`public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`

Answer (score 2):

It might be that your activity is opened repeatedly?
Print your activity dump: adb shell dumpsys activity
check the stack to see how many instances are open